# IIS 10 - Directorybrowsing should NOT display hostname/ip address

Tags: iis-10

My requirement is display files and folders without hostname/ip address as header as this can be vulnerable. And existing code working on IIS 7 and new one IIS 10.

I successfully achieved file/folder display by enabling 'Directory browsing' but unsuccessful with '**without hostname/ip address as header**'. So looking for help on this configuration part.

[The hight lighted text(localhost in this case) must not display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crj5O.png)

Comment: in iis, there is no option to customize the directory browsing page. if you wnats to do that you need to write your own module and configure it with iis.

Comment: Ok so you mean even I can not customize http request or response ?

Comment: you could customize the response header.